# Choice program in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a program that sends a message after a user makes a choice, but after the choice is made then it just closes cmd. Here's the program.

```
@echo off
title Get A Life
cd C:
:menu
cls
echo I take no responsibility for your actions. Beyond this point it is you that   has the power to kill yourself. If you press ‘x’ then your PC will be formatted. Do not cry if you loose your data or anything.
pause
echo Pick your option:
echo 1. Die slowly
echo 2. Instant Death
echo 3. Stay Away From This One
echo 4. Die this way (For Wimps!)
echo 5. Easy way out
set input=nothing
set /p input=Choice:
if %input%=1
then msg * Your computer will now sutdown
else GOTO END
if %input%=2
then msg * Your hard drive will now be formatted
else GOTO END
if %input%=3
then msg * FINE! JUST PICK THE MIDDLE ONE!
else GOTO end
if %input%=4 
then msg * Can you guess what happens next?
else GOTO END
if %input%=5
then START %documents%/%Personal Projects%/Cool trick.bat
:END
```

Comment: Completely wrong `if` syntax. See `if /?`. May I suggest using the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
@echo off
title Get A Life
cd C:
:menu
cls
echo I take no responsibility for your actions. Beyond this point it is you that   has the power to kill yourself. If you press ‘x’ then your PC will be formatted. Do not cry if you loose your data or anything.
pause
echo Pick your option:
echo 1. Die slowly
echo 2. Instant Death
echo 3. Stay Away From This One
echo 4. Die this way (For Wimps!)
echo 5. Easy way out
set input=nothing
set /p input=Choice:

if %input%==1 (
    msg * Your computer will now sutdown
) else if %input%==2 (
    msg * Your hard drive will now be formatted
) else if %input%==3 (
    msg * FINE! JUST PICK THE MIDDLE ONE!
) else if %input%==4 (
    msg * Can you guess what happens next?
) else if %input%==5 (
    START %documents%/%Personal Projects%/Cool trick.bat
)
:END
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what language that is, but here it is in Windows batch:

```
@echo off
title Get A Life
cd C:
:menu
cls
echo I take no responsibility for your actions. Beyond this point it is you that   has the power to kill yourself. If you press ‘x’ then your PC will be formatted. Do not cry if you loose your data or anything.
pause
echo Pick your option:
echo 1. Die slowly
echo 2. Instant Death
echo 3. Stay Away From This One
echo 4. Die this way (For Wimps!)
echo 5. Easy way out
set input=nothing
set /p input="Choice: "

for %%I in (1 2 3 4 5) do if "%choice%"=="%%I" goto run%%I
goto :EOF

:run1
echo * Your computer will now sutdown
goto :EOF

:run2
echo * Your hard drive will now be formatted
goto :EOF

:run3
echo * FINE! JUST PICK THE MIDDLE ONE!
goto :EOF

:run4
echo * Can you guess what happens next?
goto :EOF

:run5
START %documents%/%Personal Projects%/Cool trick.bat
```